# Adding multiple nodes using a single form

Tags: 7, nodes, media

I want a user to be able to create n nodes of type "Photo Gallery Photo" using a single form.

The node would have the following fields:

- name (For the entire upload; only shown once)
- phone number (For the entire upload; only shown once)
- town (For the entire upload; only shown once)
- email (For the entire upload; only shown once)
- title (per photo)
- description (per photo)
- photo (Image, per photo)
- galleries (node reference checkboxes, per photo)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is so specific to your implementation; what you want to do is create a node with some single value fields and multiple images, each image with a title, description and nodereference.

It is the last part of the above that is actually the question: How do you add fields to an image?

- The [file entity module](http://drupal.org/project/file_entity) allows you to add fields to a file, but those fields are not available on the node edit form, you have to go to admin/content/file to add these values.
- The [Field Collection Module](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection) allows you to define a set of fields, so on your node you would define a field collection field which has an image, a caption, nodereferences or whatever. (not too clear...try it out)

Answer (score 0):

You should write a module that saves a node for each set of values. That's doable.

Anyway that's a strange approach. I think i could be of more help knowing more details about your final purpose

Comment: This is not the answer. Please use comments.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work for you

[Multi Node Add](https://www.drupal.org/project/multi_node_add)

> This module provides a new interface for creating nodes where the users are able to select the fields what they want to use for creating the nodes.
>
> It is designed to create multiple nodes in one round, it's possible to add more node input rows on-the-fly

In your Navigation menu (the menu with your username as title) you should see a link called Create multiple nodes, -- links to the URL `http://<yoursite>/multi_node_add`

Answer (score 0):

Use the [file entity](http://drupal.org/project/file_entity) module!

You can create a new content type called Album. Add the fields you want (name, phone number, town, email, images). Then using the file entity module, create a new file type or edit the already created one (Image) and add the fields (title, description). Every time you add a new photo to the Album, the image fields will show under the uploaded photo.